# How to launch chrome browser from java

Tags: java, google-chrome

Is there any smart way to launch the chrome browser from a java class? I'm asking because I would like a smart way to launch an application that required a chrome browser on a machine that has internet explorer as a default browser and java 1.4.2 installed.

thanks

Comment: [Java 1.4.2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_1.4_.28February_6.2C_2002.29) from February 2002? Why are you running such an old version?

Comment: bc my company is too far behind the rest!

Comment: If that's the case, why do you think the machines have chrome?

Comment: the plan is to install chrome on the machines. But the version of java cannot be upgraded because of other software that relies on 1.4.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can execute `chrome.exe` like this:

```
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe\"");
    p.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Google Chrome launched!");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Provided you know where Chrome is installed.

Comment: Just what I was thinking!

Answer (score 3):

You can try Selenium [Here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable
    {
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/google-chrome");

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
}
```

}

Add Maven Dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.42.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the best way I found for this problem, since it does not matter where the browser is installed or whatever, java communicates with the operating system and makes a request to run the default browser.

```
String url = "https://yourdomain.org/";
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse( java.net.URI.create(url));
```