# open Java Application directly

Tags: java, google-chrome, web-applications, jnlp

I have an HTML with a link to an Oracle Java application (Intranet). When I open the link with Internet Explorer, the application starts immediately. When I open the link with Chrome, the browser downloads a *.jnlp file, after clicking on this file the application starts. 
It is also possible to start directly in Chrome?

1000 thanks

Comment: this is the code for my link:
onclick="window.open('link2server/application', '_blank')"

Comment: Please try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320890/how-to-launch-chrome-browser-from-java

Comment: this is the false direction... I want to start a application with chrome and not chrome with an application!?