# I want to open link or URL on browser with Java code

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, url, amazon-s3, hyperlink

I have a URL(like: "https://www.google.co.in/") that should be open on browser(on same browser where my application is running.) at run time from Java code.

Searched many thing and found below java code but it's not working for me.

```
Desktop desktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
URI uri = new URI(String.valueOf("My_Url"));
desktop.browse(uri);
```

While using above code, i am getting below exception

```
java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop(Desktop.java:142)
```

Also i have added and tried with below line of code with static block and without static block and getting same exception. Please suggest.

```
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320890/how-to-launch-chrome-browser-from-java

Comment: Desktop.getDesktop() throws a HeadlessException if the system it is run on is headless, as there is no desktop available on such systems. Is that the case for you?

Comment: @AUsername When i'm using below code from main method it's working fine but in my spring boot application it's throwing java.awt.HeadlessException exception.
```
Desktop desktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
```

Answer (score 0):

use ProcessBuilder

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    list.add("start"); 
    list.add("www.google.com");
    ProcessBuilder build = new ProcessBuilder(list);
    build.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work?

```
String url = "http://www.google.co.in";

        if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()){
            Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            try {
                desktop.browse(new URI(url));
            } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            try {
                runtime.exec("xdg-open " + url);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Note that `xdg-open` will only work on unix systems and not even all. I usually go for `x-www-browser` which promisses to run under all unix distros, using an x-server.

Comment: First condition is always false because i am using spring boot application but while using main method it's working fine. is there any issue with spring container?

Comment: Below code is also working from main method but same is not working from my spring boot application.
 Desktop desktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium Web Driver for opening a website into browser.
click here to see web driver setup [how to setup](https://www.guru99.com/installing-selenium-webdriver.html)

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class OpenSite
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        // tries to open https://google.com
        driver.get("https://google.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: Without Selenium Web Driver is there other way  to open URL in browser?  Downloading Selenium dependency to open a URL only is not a good practice.